# Using Dapper's QueryMultiple with new DynamicParameters for each entry

Tags: c#, postgresql

I have created dynamic parameters for a C# object like

```
DynamicParameters parameters = GetDynamicParametersFromAttributes(attributes, entity);
```

Which is to be mapped to a

```
string insertRawSql = INSERT INTO entity (columns) VALUES (@name @description @values @etc)
```

And these can be passed as

```
connection.QuerySingle(insertRawSql, parameters);
```

Which will replace the `@values` with the dynamic parameters. First page of the manual.

But let's say I have

```
names = ("foo", "bar, "baz")
descriptions = ("desc1", "desc2", "desc3")
values = ...
```

How can I restructure this into a faster `QueryMultiple`, if the parameters are different for every insert? For example, a list of (parameters_insert1, parameters_insert2, ...parameters_insertn)?

Comment: It may be a lot easier to use an additional library with Dapper, such as this - https://dapper-tutorial.net/insert . You could create a list of POCO objects, then insert them together in a single query.  It would handle the parameters for you.

Comment: Dapper.Contrib Nuget package have `Insert` and `InsertAsync` methods.

Comment: It doesn't really explain how to convert `connection.QuerySingle(rawSQL params)` to `connection.Insert`. Can it be a tuple? A dict? Or only multiple strings? But how do I combine my dapper params with the sql string then?